# Split responsive menu into two coloumns

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu, responsive

This is the website I'm working on http://www.jokerleb.com/ and I'm using this https://responsive.menu, the free version. it will appear on devices 400px and smaller.

How to split its columns into 2 like so?

[image]

Don't know how to edit the CSS to make it look right, if it's possible in the first place.

Comment: You'll actually want to go post this over on StackOverflow which is the sister site to this one. SO deals with general programming questions as well as CSS and such. This site is specific to WordPress development.

Comment: @belinus I flagged it for migration, thanks for notifying me, moderators will take a look at it and decide

Comment: Where's the code you're working with currently? And you're just looking to make 2 columns in the responsive menu that slides out in the "free" examples on http://responsive.menu?

Comment: Try to use media query in your css depends on your device width

Comment: @MichaelCoker the examples don't offer a design like in the picture, I don't know where the code is, having a hard time locating the css in inspect element. The plugin doesn't say much

Comment: @Lynob what do you mean you don't know where the code is? You don't have any code? You replied to a comment below *"I tried it and it's currently in the css, i used it inside `@media screen and (max-width: 400px)` didn't work"* - you tried what with what code? Share that code please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adds these lines to your code :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    #responsive-menu-container{
        width:100%;
    }

    #responsive-menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    #responsive-menu li{
        width:50%;
    }
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), so something like this should do it for you:

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
     #responsive-menu-container li.responsive-menu-item {
         width: 50%;
         display: inline-block;
     }
}
</style>
```

Note that you may need to play around with this CSS a little, since widths will vary based upon `padding`, `margin` and the `display` type.  If you provide a sample of your CSS (or better yet a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)) I can help you more exactly.

The lines above make it look like this once the category button is clicked:
[image]

If you'd prefer the thing go the whole width, include this in your `@media` option as well:

```
#responsive-menu-container {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: don't know where the code is, having a hard time locating the css in inspect element. The plugin doesn't say much

Comment: Is it the `menu-header` list you're trying to edit?  If so, where I have `.row` inside the `@media` section, I would just replace that with `#menu-header li.menu-item`

Comment: I tried it and it's currently in the css, i used it inside `@media screen and (max-width: 400px)` didn't work

Comment: @Lynob I updated my answer and included a screenshot.